# Is it correct to say "a hasty man" meaning the person has a hasty manner of his behavior?

Tags: word-usage

Can "hasty" be used relating to people? For example:
He is hasty. = He does things in a hasty manner. / He often hastens.

Answer (score 2):

[Hasty](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hasty) is generally used about decisions or actions. It can be used about people, but only about a specific decision, linked with the preposition **in**, for example:

> We were a little hasty in appointing him as headmaster

In my opinion, it can't be used about a person's character. You might consider using rush as a verb if somebody does things faster than is wise:

> James in inclined to rush when something doesn't interest him

Comment: You didn't mention the word "_hurried_". From [a dictionary](http://www.britannica.com/dictionary/hurried): "_a hurried waitress_" — Is this phrase natural to you? Thanks.

Comment: "Hurried" is used about somebody who is being pressured by other people, or circumstance, to do things quickly. Like the waitress in your example, it has nothing to do with her character- it is only a result of the situation that she is in.

Comment: I wouldn't use _perfunctory_ to describe a person either - just an action.

Comment: "_James is inclined to **rush** when something doesn't interest him_" — As I understand, we can replace "_rush_" with "_hurry_" or "_hasten_" here without changing the sentence meaning. Is it so? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii  No, "hurry" and "hasten" are far from perfect synonyms for "rush" in your sentence.  **Hurry** is not associated with boredom or lack of interest.  **Hasten** is a rather old-fashioned 19th c. word, but it, too, is not associated with lack of interest. **Rush**, on the other hand, is often found in contexts where something has been done in a slipshod manner.  And there is the verb "to rush it" meaning to go *too* fast when doing something, using less care and attention to detail than is required.  "Don't rush it. Take your time. It's delicate and you could easily ruin it."

Comment: @KateBunting fair comment. I have removed that from my answer.